# HTML-CSS: Make background (linear-gradient) responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive, background-color

I have a wrapper with a header, that only contains an image and below there is some content.

My div has the default values:

```
min-width: 300px
max-width: 960px
```

I want a linear-gradient background and till now I have this:

```
background: rgb(164, 29, 32);
background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(164, 29, 32, 1) 0%, rgba(164, 29, 32, 1) 30%, rgba(78, 58, 47, 1) 75%, rgba(63, 41, 29, 0.3) 80%, rgba(67, 39, 27, 0) 100%);
```

On fullscreen-size everything is perfect and how I want it to be:
[image: Normal width]

but e.g. on mobile the background is like this:

[image: lower width]

Is there a way that the background "stays" at the position and that there doesnt appear that white space?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The images are very narrow and nothing is clear from them.. Please check the images

Comment: You might enhance this question with some HTML and working CSS applied to it so we can best assist you here.

Comment: Declaring your `background` property twice would seem to be a mistake, as the second declaration immediately overrides the first.

Comment: Removed the first background, didnt change anything...

What part of my code I can provide here would help in this case?